# Using Django's JSONResponseMixin to respond to AJAX requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-class-based-views

I'm working with Django & AJAX. Basically, I simply want the javascript (vote.js) to POST some data 
to the Django View, and in turn, the View to respond with a JSON data to the html, so that my javascript's callback function can use that response from the server.

So here is my code:

**vote.js**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.upvote', function() {
    .....

    var xhr = {
        'id': id,
        'upvote': upvote,
    };

    $.post(location.href, xhr, function(data) {
        question.find('.rating').html(data.rating)
    });

    return false;
});
```

**views.py**

```
//I copied this JSONResponseMixin directly from official Django doc
class JSONResponseMixin(object):
    def render_to_response(self, context):
        "Returns a JSON response containing 'context' as payload"
        return self.get_json_response(self.convert_context_to_json(context))

    def get_json_response(self, content, **httpresponse_kwargs):
        "Construct an `HttpResponse` object."
        return http.HttpResponse(content,
                                 content_type='application/json',
                                 **httpresponse_kwargs)

    def convert_context_to_json(self, context):
        "Convert the context dictionary into a JSON object"
        # Note: This is *EXTREMELY* naive; in reality, you'll need
        # to do much more complex handling to ensure that arbitrary
        # objects -- such as Django model instances or querysets
        # -- can be serialized as JSON.
        return json.dumps(context)


class MyListView(JSONResponseMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, DetailView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        .....

        data = {'rating': question.rating}

        return render_to_response(data)


    def render_to_response(self, context):
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return JSONResponseMixin.render_to_response(self, context)
        else:
            return TemplateResponseMixin.render_to_response(self, context)
```

However, doing this and clicking my "vote" button in html that triggers the javascript POST gives me a TemplateDoesNotExist error:

**Error**

```
.....
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 139, in find_template                                                      
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)                                               
TemplateDoesNotExist: {'rating': 1}
```

Well it looks like my last 5 lines of views.py are working properly. 
Any idea??? :(((

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyListView(JSONResponseMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, DetailView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        id = request.POST.get('id')
        .....

        data = {'rating': question.rating}

        return render_to_response(data)
```

You end up calling the wrong `render_to_response` method here, namely the shortcut function in `django.shortcuts`, which I'd guess you've imported in your views.py.

Use `return self.render_to_response(data)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response

render_to_response needs template name as the first argument.